# KeyStore carregando todos os certificados

Tags: java, autenticação, certificado-digital, keystore

Estou criando um *webService* que faz conexão com o sistema do [eSocial](http://portal.esocial.gov.br), que obriga a ter autenticação Mutua.

Quando eu possuo apenas um certificado na maquina, não acontece problema nenhum, porém quando ele possui 2+ certificados, eu não consigo fazer com que o usuário escolha o certificado que realizara a conexão mutua, ele simplesmente cria a conexão com o primeiro certificado da lista.

Gostaria que o usuário escolhe-se o certificado que ele realizara a conexão.

Quando eu dou um simples no *KeyStore*, ele carrega com todos os certificados

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
        InputStream io = tokenAladdin();
        try {
            ks.load(null, "@Techne".toCharArray());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Gostaria de saber, porque a janela de escolha de certificado não abre.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: também estou trabalhando com o eSocial, mas estou desenvolvendo em C#/VB.NET. No .NET há um método pronto que exibe o diálogo para que o usuário escolha o certificado desejado: > X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection Eu fiz uma pesquisa rápida e achei essa solução para o Java:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080214/windows-security-dialog-for-selecting-a-certificate-in-java Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 1):

user101666, também estou trabalhando com o eSocial, mas estou desenvolvendo em C#/VB.NET. No .NET há um método pronto que exibe o diálogo para que o usuário escolha o certificado desejado:

> X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection

O seu código não abre uma janela de escolha de certificado porque você não escreveu nada para que isso aconteça. O seu código:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ks.load(null, "@Techne".toCharArray());
```

somente carrega todos os certificados armazenados nesse repositório do Windows.

Eu fiz uma pesquisa rápida sobre essa funcionalidade no Java e achei esse post no StackOverflow global:

> https://stackoverflow.com/q/23080214/8133067

Lá o usuário Florian diz que essa funcionalidade não existe pronta no Java, mas que ele escreveu uma solução em Java para exibir o diálogo do Windows para escolha de certificado. Ele colocou o projeto no GitHub:

> https://github.com/FlorianSW/org.droidwiki.certtest

E para chegar nessa solução, ele se baseou nesse outro post, do Tech Junkie:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/42088543/8133067

Mas basicamente o que eles fizeram foi acessar diretamente a função `CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore` da biblioteca **Cryptui.dll**, nativa do Windows:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380288.aspx

Vou replicar aqui o código postado pelo usuário **Tech Junkie**, que está mais fácil de postar, caso os links deixem de funcionar:

```
NativeLibrary cryptUI = NativeLibrary.getInstance("Cryptui");
NativeLibrary crypt32 = NativeLibrary.getInstance("Crypt32");

Function functionCertOpenSystemStore = crypt32.getFunction("CertOpenSystemStoreA");
Object[] argsCertOpenSystemStore = new Object[] { 0, "CA"};
HANDLE h = (HANDLE) functionCertOpenSystemStore.invoke(HANDLE.class, argsCertOpenSystemStore);

Function functionCryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore = cryptUI.getFunction("CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore");
System.out.println(functionCryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore.getName());
Object[] argsCryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore = new Object[] { h, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0};
Pointer ptrCertContext = (Pointer) functionCryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore.invoke(Pointer.class, argsCryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore);

Function functionCertGetNameString = crypt32.getFunction("CertGetNameStringW");
char[] ptrName = new char[128];
Object[] argsCertGetNameString = new Object[] { ptrCertContext, 5, 0, 0, ptrName, 128};
functionCertGetNameString.invoke(argsCertGetNameString);
System.out.println("Selected certificate is " + new String(ptrName));

Function functionCertFreeCertificateContext = crypt32.getFunction("CertFreeCertificateContext");
Object[] argsCertFreeCertificateContext = new Object[] { ptrCertContext};
functionCertFreeCertificateContext.invoke(argsCertFreeCertificateContext);

Function functionCertCloseStore = crypt32.getFunction("CertCloseStore");
Object[] argsCertCloseStore = new Object[] { h, 0};
functionCertCloseStore.invoke(argsCertCloseStore);
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Por mais que o link possa ajudar, seu post nao responde a pergunta. No futuro você terá reputaçao suficiente para comentar nas perguntas e respostas.

Answer (score 1):

Acabei resolvendo via código msm, porém eu apresento um simples combo box, e pego o alias do certificado, depois implemento somente ele em um "Repositorio de chaves"(Array de KeyManager);

```
 KeyStore ksPrivate = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
 KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("tEHCNE@".toCharArray()));

 ksPrivate.load(null, null);
 X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();
 //keySotre2.setKeyEntry("key1", (Key)keyEntry.getPrivateKey(), "tECHNE@".toCharArray(), certChain);  
 //keySotre2.setEntry(alias, keyEntry, protParam);

 HSKeyManager hsKey = new HSKeyManager(cert, keyEntry.getPrivateKey());  

 KeyManager[] keysManager = new KeyManager[]{hsKey};
```

Depois preciso apenas setar esse repositório de chaves na conexão

```
sslContext.init(keysManager, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
```

Objeto HSKeyManager.

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.X509KeyManager;

public class HSKeyManager implements X509KeyManager {

    private X509Certificate certificate;  
        private PrivateKey privateKey;  

        public HSKeyManager(X509Certificate certificate, PrivateKey privateKey) {  
            this.certificate = certificate;  
            this.privateKey = privateKey;  
        }  

        public String chooseClientAlias(String[] arg0, Principal[] arg1,  
                Socket arg2) {  
            return certificate.getIssuerDN().getName();  
        }  

        public String chooseServerAlias(String arg0, Principal[] arg1,  
                Socket arg2) {  
            return null;  
        }  

        public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(String arg0) {  
            return new X509Certificate[]{certificate};  
        }  

        public String[] getClientAliases(String arg0, Principal[] arg1) {  
            return new String[]{certificate.getIssuerDN().getName()};  
        }  

        public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String arg0) {  
            return privateKey;  
        }  

        public String[] getServerAliases(String arg0, Principal[] arg1) {  
            return null;  
        } 
}
```

Depois vou tentar sua solução